# How to programmatically remove applied discount coupons in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, discount, coupon

I've been searching for a while but I can't find how to remove woocommerce coupons programmatically.

I'm trying to make discounts based on cart total. I need to apply remove coupons because If you have products worth 1000 € (15% discount coupon applied) and remove products and leave only products worth 50 €, you still get this 15% discount because my code isn't removing the already applied coupon.

So here is my code for now:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'apply_matched_coupons' );

function apply_matched_coupons() {
    global $woocommerce;

$coupon_code5 = '5p'; // your coupon code here
$coupon_code10 = '10p'; // your coupon code here
$coupon_code15 = '15p'; // your coupon code here
$coupon_code20 = '20p'; // your coupon code here
$coupon_code25 = '25p'; // your coupon code here

   if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ){ 
return;
}

   if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 4000 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code25 );
        $woocommerce->show_messages();
    }
else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 2000 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code20 );
        $woocommerce->show_messages();
    }
else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 1000 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code15 );
        $woocommerce->show_messages();
    }
else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 500 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code10 );
        $woocommerce->show_messages();
    }
else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 200 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code5 );
        $woocommerce->show_messages();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

To remove a single coupon from the cart using its coupon code use [`WC_Cart->remove_coupon( $code )`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_remove_coupon).

To remove all coupons from the cart you would use [`WC_Cart->remove_coupons( $type )`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_remove_coupons) - `$type` defaults to `null` for all, pass in "cart" to remove before tax coupons, "order" for after tax coupons.

To get all of the coupons in the cart as an `array` you can loop over and optionally remove, use [`WC_Cart->get_coupons()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_coupons).

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ){
   $valid = ? // decide to remove or not
   if ( ! $valid ){
       WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $code );
   }
}
```

Comment: Removing the coupon worked for me but the discounted total still remains. How do you update the cart totals via Ajax ?

Comment: @nickstaw Put `WC()->cart->calculate_totals();` after `WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $code );` this will recalculate the totals of cart

Answer (score 10):

The cart method remove_coupons() has been since updated such that a type is no longer required. Now, to remove all coupons, this will do the trick:

`WC()->cart->remove_coupons();`

For more information, check out the documentation for the WC_Cart class [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about this one :)

Comment: I have found when using this method, that although it did remove all existing coupons that were applied to the cart, it did not then recalculate the price.

Comment: @WongKongPhooey Yes, get_discount_total will return old result.